# mysite.com/api and mysite/images not being aliased to my domain

Tags: express, dns, cloudflare

I have a site being hosted on heroku  so I can go to myapp.herokuapp.com/ and my SPA loads.  I got a domain and used cloudflare with a CName record to alais mydomain.com to myapp.herokuapp.com.  Great the sites load.  Within my SPA i load some images.   If my app loads  directly from heroku  *myapp.herokuapp.com/images/filex.png"  it works fine but if I call (or type in the address bar)  myDomain.com/images/files.png"  I just get my site back like i types mydomain.com

Is this an issue with cloudflare?  Do i need additional routing rules?
or is this an issue with my express server that is serving the app and images?  does the redirected
request look different and do I need to add code to handle the redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have been an issue with heroku. It’s working fine on aws.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the redirect is happening without more information. My best guess is that you need to follow [these instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) from Heroku. Without this, Heroku servers will have no idea what to do with a request that has a host header of mydomain.com, and will perform in some unexpected way. Heroku needs some way on its side to know that all mydomain.com requests should be handled identically to myapp.herokuapp.com requests.

If this configuration is already in place, your underlying code needs to handle myapp.herokuapp.com and mydomain.com, but I believe by default express will not care about hostname.